# docker.service - How to edit systemd service file?

Tags: linux, systemd, docker

Need to edit following entries:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always
```

in `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file

---

```
$ sudo -E systemctl edit docker.service
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

did not update the service file after restart(`sudo systemctl restart docker.service`)

---

What is the recommended approach to edit service file(`docker.service`)?

Comment: Does `systemctl daemon-reload` help? What does `systemctl cat docker` show? And `systemctl show docker`?

Comment: @StephenKitt No it doesn't but why `systemctl restart` doesn't?

Comment: Just to baby-step it, the man page says that the updates are "written to the real location if the editor exits successfully.". I assume you exited your editor successfully? It does also say that "After the units have been edited, systemd configuration is reloaded (in a way that is equivalent to
           daemon-reload)."

Comment: Another issue is, `systemctl restart` in EC2 requires passwd, which I don't know

Comment: Let me ask again... What does `systemctl cat docker` show? And `systemctl show docker`? (Please [edit] your question to show the output of those commands.)

Comment: Thanks for helping figuring out where is the docker service file located

Answer (score 5):

I found the [using the `systemctl edit` command](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configuring-remote-access-with-systemd-unit-file) was tricky (using Ubuntu 18.04), so I did this:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
```

then added the lines I required, in your case:
(and yes, the apparently empty first `ExecStart=` line is not a mistake)

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Next reload, restart and check it's listening on the specified port:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
sudo netstat -lntp | grep dockerd
```